# Lord of the Ring LCG - Doubt on "Feint" (Core Set) functioning

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings-lcg

*Feint* says

**Combat Action**: Choose an enemy engaged with a player. That enemy cannot attack that player this phase.

By playing this card, I'm creating a "can't"-type effect which prevents an enemy from attacking.

How this interact with shadow cards? Specifically:

1. Should I still deal the shadow card to the enemy or not?
2. If the answer to the previous question is "yes", should I reveal and eventually resolve the shadow card?

My doubt arise from the fact that I'm just preventing the "attack" of the enemy, and is not clear to me if the shadow card management is to be considered as an inner step of the entire (prevented) attack action OR is to be considered as a separate thing from the prevented attack action.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should still deal the shadow card to the enemy even if you play Feint. Dealing shadow cards is a separate step from the enemy's attack, and it happens before you have a chance to play Feint. So, even if you prevent the enemy from attacking, they will still have a shadow card in play.

No, you should not reveal and eventually resolve the shadow card. The shadow card is only resolved if the enemy makes an attack. Since Feint prevents the enemy from attacking, the shadow card will remain unresolved and will be discarded at the end of the combat phase.

Here is the specific rule that covers this situation:

At the end of the combat phase, discard each unresolved shadow card in play.

The shadow card is unresolved; so, it will be discarded at the end of the combat phase.